# Asking pandas if a value is missing doesn't work despite working fine just some lines above

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write a code to replace missing values in a dataset. The rule to replace them is to use lagrange polynomial interpolation with 4 known points, to interpolate the missing data according to its position.

So what my code is intended to do is the following: first I added two for loops to go through every single data point in my dataframe, first by columns and then by rows. Once it's in a column, it will iterate over every row until it finds a missing value. I did it this way so I know the exact position of every missing value. Now, the code will try to find the first two non missing values to the right of the missing value it found Let me make myself clear, suppose we are in column 3 and the missing value is in the row 73, the code will test the value on the row 74 to see if it's missing, then the 75 and so on, until it finds exactly two, every time it finds a valid value it stores it in a list, and then the corresponding value to that column and row in another list (suppose the 74th and 75th value are non missing, it will then create two lists t = [74, 75] and x = [f(74), f(75)], where f(i) is the value on the i-th cell in a given column). The process to find the non missing values to the left is the exact same. Finally it runs a lagrange polynomial interpolation I wrote and replaces the missing values on a copy of the dataframe.

One deficiency of the code just as I described was that if there was only one valid value to the left or right of the missing value we are working with, the code would just not work. For example, if the missing value was on the row 1 (the second row), there would only be one value before it, the one in row 0. So I tried to code some restrictions: if i (the row of the missing value) plus k (the amount of spaces to the left or right we move to find a valid value) is lower than zero or greater than the number of rows, the code would just ignore such value and just leave it as a NaN.

Problem is my code doesn't seem to work, it says it throws an error on

```
if pd.notna(df[column][i + k]):
```

I really don't understand why is that, since just some lines above I used

```
if pd.isna(df[column][i]):
```

And that line doesn't throw an error at all.

This is my whole code

```
import pandas as pd
import Lagrange #module of mine

df = pd.read_excel(r'pathname') #read data
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None) #show all data

redf = df

for column in df: #iterate over columns
    for i in df.index: #iterate over rows
        if pd.isna(df[column][i]): #detect missing values
            t = []
            x = []
            k = 0
            while len(t) <= 2: #find valid data to the right of the missing value
                k = k + 1
                if i + k <= len(df.index):
                    if pd.notna(df[column][i + k]):
                        t.append(i + k)
                        x.append(df[column][i + k])
                else:
                    break
            if len(t) != 2:
                continue
            k = 0
            while len(t) <= 4: #find valid data to the left of the missing value
                k = k - 1
                if i + k >= 0:
                    if pd.notna(df[column][i + k]):
                        t.append(i + k)
                        x.append(df[column][i + k])
                else:
                    break
            if len(t) != 4:
                continue
            intpol = Lagrange.lagrange(t, x, i)
            redf._set_value(i, column, intpol)

print(redf)
```

This is what happens when I run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/IRVING/PycharmProjects/giraffe/test3.py", line 18, in <module>
    if pd.notna(df[column][i + k]):
  File "C:\Users\IRVING\PycharmProjects\giraffe\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 871, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Users\IRVING\PycharmProjects\giraffe\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4405, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 90, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 997, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1004, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 74

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any explanation or help about this issue will be really appreciated, and you can also help me to optimize my code in general, I think the way I found the valid data next to the missing value is kinda clunky. Many thanks if you take the time to answer me

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: It just says traceback most recent call and quotes the line i'm having trouble with, after that it writes some errors in lines on the pandas module.

Comment: What is the error type? Index out of range?

Comment: I'm gonna edit the post to show what the program says

Comment: I solved it. I used len(df.index) as the restriction, but that was one row too many. I'm not used to counting rows from 0 to "n - 1" so I just got confused in that part